# ¿Como comparar dos JButton en un mismo evento?

Tags: java, eventos

Estoy aprendiendo Java. He re-formulado la pregunta, veo que el error es otro.

Quizás la pregunta no sea del todo correcta.
Estoy practicando aprendiendo,  creando un juego de encontrar parejas, de momento lo estoy haciendo mediante `JButton` y el texto correspondiente, al pulsar dos `JButton` iguales, se visualizarían y quedarían visibles como un acierto en caso contrario, se volverían a quedar en blanco.

Al añadir los botones y realizar la comprobación de cual es el `String` del botón para después poder compararlos("que no se si sería correcto así") me aparece como que el `String` del botón es el último añadido, ¿Cuál es el error que cometo?

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
     
     Marco juego=new Marco();
     juego.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
     
 }

}

class Marco extends JFrame{
 public Marco(){ 
     setVisible(true);
     setBounds(500,300,500,300);
     setTitle("Cada oveja con su pareja");       
     Lamina milamina=new Lamina();
     add(milamina);
 }
}

class Lamina extends JPanel{
 
 public Lamina(){
     
     
     setLayout(new BorderLayout());
     Texto_principal =new JLabel("Combina cada imagen igual al suyo");
     JPanel Lamina_Norte = new JPanel();
     Lamina_Norte.add(Texto_principal);
     add(Lamina_Norte, BorderLayout.NORTH);
     Lamina_Centro = new JPanel();   
     Lamina_Centro.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,3));   
     
     
     CartaBocaAbajo cartas1 = new CartaBocaAbajo();
     cartas1.AddCartasBocaAbajo("src/cada_oveja_pareja/1.png","1");
     cartas1.AddCartasBocaAbajo("src/cada_oveja_pareja/1.png","2");
     cartas1.AddCartasBocaAbajo("src/cada_oveja_pareja/1.png","3");
     cartas1.AddCartasBocaAbajo("src/cada_oveja_pareja/1.png","4");
     
     
     add(Lamina_Centro, BorderLayout.CENTER);
     
     
 }
 private class CartaBocaAbajo implements ActionListener{
     
     public CartaBocaAbajo(){
         
 
     }

     private void AddCartasBocaAbajo(String ruta, String nombreCarta){
         
         bocaAbajo=new ImageIcon(ruta,nombreCarta );
         imagen = new JButton(bocaAbajo);
         imagen.addActionListener(this);
         Lamina_Centro.add(imagen);  
 
     }
     
     
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
     
         
         System.out.println(((ImageIcon) bocaAbajo).getDescription());
         
         // if(imagen.getIcon().toString().equals(imagen.getIcon().toString()))
           //  {
             // System.out.println(imagen);
             
             //}
          
 
     }
 
 }
```

Seguro que puedo mejorar el código, así que disculpas al leerlo, agradezco vuestra paciencia.

Comment: Te recomiendo que añadas todo el código relacionado con esto, ya que ahí veo que utilizas variables que no sé de dónde salen ni cómo las recoges (comparador?).
Para hacer esto sería muy fácil extender la clase JButton y añadirle una variable que sea el "contenido" del botón, luego sobreescribes el método equals o le añades un método propio para comprobar si son iguales y ya tendrías toda la lógica implementada, ya que podrías usarlos como JButton normales y además llevan toda la lógica necesaria para el juego

Comment: Buenos días @aseron1988. Me parece que deberías orientar el código a una lógica que no dependa de los JButtons. Yo sugeriría que generes clases que modelen el juego y que no tengan que ver con componentes gráficos y que luego los componentes gráficos en sus eventos pregunten a las clases del modelo por los estatus que tienen (el Modelo Vista Controlador )   y bueno como estas aprendiendo Java te diré que esta mal nombrada la clase, no estas siguiendo estándares. Debería llamarse: EventoPulsaBoton

Comment: @AlvaroC.  he reformulado la pregunta, a ver si así podéis ayudarme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He analizado tu código. La razón de que te muestre siempre como si pulsaras en el último boton que agregaste es que en el método **actionPerformed** estas usando la variable **bocaAbajo**  esa variable la usaste para ir pintando los botones. Al terminar de pintar se quedo con el último botón y ya de ahí no ha cambiado.

Mi sugerencia es no usar la variable **bocaAbajo**, no la necesitas.

Prueba usando el siguiente código:

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    JButton elBotonPulsado = ((JButton)e.getSource());
    ImageIcon icono = (ImageIcon) elBotonPulsado.getIcon();
    System.out.println("El boton es: "+ icono.getDescription());         
}
```

El método **actionPerformed** recibe un **ActionEvent** ese parámetro trae una referencia al objeto sobre el cual se aplico la acción. En este caso como la acción la disparo un **JButton** podemos hacer el casteo y recuperar la referencia.

Luego como a cada botón le pusiste un **ImageIcon** podemos hacer otro casteo para recuperar la imagen y como a cada **ImageIcon** le pusiste una descripción pues esto ya debería de pintarte el valor que esperas

Como te coloque en un comentario ahora que estas aprendiendo pon cuidado en el nombrado estandar de las variables y las clases:

Siempre los nombres de clases deben iniciar en mayúscula con notación de camello, nunca con guiones bajos, nunca todo en mayuscula, nunca deben empezar con minúscula  ejemplo de nombres correctos:  MiClase, EstaEsUnaClase, ImageIcon, ActionEvent

Siempre los nombres de método deben iniciar con minúscula nunca los separes por guiones bajos, los nombres de método deben representar acciones. Ejemplos de nombres correctos:   sumaValores, ejecuta,  run, actionPerformed, stop, addActionListener, add

Siempre los nombres de variables deben iniciar en minúscula, usar notación de camello, nunca usar guiones bajos y deben representar sustantivos. Ejemplos de nombres correctos:  perro, sumando, botonGuardar, icono, ventana, marcoPrincipal

Siempre las constantes debes manejarlas en mayúsculas y con guiones bajos. Ejemplo: TAMANIO_MAXIMO, PI, PATH_FINAL

Los estándares son importantes, hay frameworks que dan por hecho que estas escribiendo código bien estandarizado y que fallaran si no lo haces así, es mejor que desde el inicio te acostumbres a generar código de calidad que cualquier desarrollador pueda leer sin dificultad infiriendo correctamente si lo que has puesto es una clase, un método, una variable o una constante sin tener que examinar demasiado el código.

Dudas o comentarios estoy a tus ordenes.