# Estado de servidor mysql desde java test de conexion a server

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

Buen día, intento realizar un swich de control, que me verifique si la data base remota esta activa, operable. Mi idea es usar una imagen que dependiendo del estado del servidor remoto de mysql cambie de estado, a si esta on (activa) a off (si no es posible la conexión).

He construido el siguiente codigo y de momento me sirve, yo lo que realmente queria era hacerlo con imagenes.

```
        try {
        //ABRO CONEXION
        var url = "jdbc:mysql://freedatabase:3306/xxxxx?useSSL=false&useTimezone=GMT%2D3&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true";
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "user", "pass");
        mySqlStatus.setBackground(Color.green);
        mySqlStatus.setText("ON");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        mySqlStatus.setBackground(Color.red);
        mySqlStatus.setText("OFF");
    } finally {
        
    }
```

Logre que quede de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**1er punto** Pero me gustaría saber si el código no deja abierta la conexión a la base de datos, o si realmente se cierra al agregar el finally después del catch.

**2do punto** También me gustaría saber si existe la posibilidad de que al abrir la ventana de la aplicación, automáticamente el botón se ejecute. E intentado ponerlo como constructor dentro del public ventanaDB que es la ventana principal pero me dice que al ser un botón requiere una acción previa.

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. Dos comentarios: 1) Usar un control puede hacer que el usuario espere que puede manipular ese switch (y por lo que leo, no es así). Usa otra forma de informarlo que no dé la idea de interacción. 2) Puedes hacer una consulta sencilla y barata cada N tiempo y si el resultado es el esperado, mantienes el mensaje de conectado o desconectado. Puedes incluso revisar si algo en JDBC 4 te permite esa validación sin hacer una consulta. Sin código en tu pregunta, es difícil que recibas algo más específico

Comment: Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour). 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes. Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario y añadir info relevante como [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Es extraño tener que avisarle a un usuario que una base de datos no esta disponible. Un constructor de JButton acepta una imágen, revisa [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/385785).

Comment: Sobre el finally, siempre se ejecuta por lo que si quieres cerrar la conexión debes colocarlo en el finally, recomendable también que para esta validación la variable _con_ sea local, ya que si la mantienes global y es usada en otro método puedes afectar otros usos. Para validar la conexión "onLoad" podrías intentar con _addWindowsListener_ y su método _windowOpened_ si estás usando _JFrame_.